# Visual Studio needs to make non-functional changes to this project to open in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, migration

I opened a C# project that was created in VS 2010 SP, with VS 2013. A one-way conversion window appeared where I proceeded with the conversion.
Following warning message appeared

"Visual Studio needs to make non-functional changes to this project in order to enable the project to open in Visual Studio 2013, Visual Studio 2012, and Visual Studio 2010 SP1 without impacting project behavior."

when I run the application it gives the following error

Description: An error occurred while accessing the resources required to serve this request. The server may not be configured for access to the requested URL.

Error message 401.2.: Unauthorized: Logon failed due to server configuration.  Verify that you have permission to view this directory or page based on the credentials you supplied and the authentication methods enabled on the Web server.  Contact the Web server's administrator for additional assistance.

If I run the same app in VS 2010 it works fine.In VS 2013 upgraded the MVC3 to MVC 4 using these steps 
http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc4-release-notes#_Toc303253806

Comment: What's the question? :)

Comment: how to fix that error, am opening sol in vs 2013 and not able to run the applicaiton

Comment: Well. What is the error?

Comment: updated with some more info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution worked for me, but depends on the type of security utilised by your application.  I required Windows Authentication to be used as the application was running on our local intranet.

Anyway, my problem lay with the default IIS Express settings for running the app. These can be found in your default **My Documents** folder for the **IISExpress\config** folder and modify the **applicationhost.config** settings to your liking.